# Oracle APEX 18 Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle, grid, oracle-apex, interactive

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible in Oracle APEX interactive grids. I'm wanting to insert a string of text like "Y" into a cell simply by clicking the cell. I'm trying to avoid using a checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blockquote

Please follow the below steps to achieve the desired result

Paste the below JavaScript code in Function and Global Variable Decleration:

```js
function fSwitch(ptext) {
  if(ptext == 'Y') {
     return ("");
  }
  else {
     return 'Y'
  }
}
```

Make the Interactive Grid Editable

Change Column Type of the column that you want to insert a string to "Text Field".

Paste the below code in the Advanced -> Custom Attributes  of the column that you want to insert a string

```js
onclick="javascript:this.value=fSwitch(this.value)"; onkeypress="return false;"
```

How this works:

On focus of the column cell,

1. If the cell is empty 'Y' will be entered,
2. If the cell contains 'Y' then the cell value becomes NULL;

Comment: This doesn't quite work, but something is happening. The very first time I try it, I have to double click, not single-click, and it will enter a "Y" into the cell. However, it only works once. If I click or double-click another row, nothing happens at all. Also, it will not remove the "Y" by clicking in the cell again. However, if I manually enter any character other than a "Y", it will automatically remove it with a single-click.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I have modified the code that is used in the Custom Attributes section. Please use the code that I have modified. Please make sure that the IG is in Edit mode when you perform this action(this will avoid the double click). I have added code in such a way that you cannot type anything in that field.

Comment: Thank you. It works better now. I'm clicking the Edit button to put it in edit mode, then I'm double-clicking the cell to automatically add the text, which works fine. Then to remove the text, I just need to click once. This will work fine for me. Having never written javascript before, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in "Switch" type for interactive grids which can be used to create yes/no columns. Would that work?

For an example, go to the App Gallery and install the Sample Interactive Grids app. Run it and navigate to Editing > Other Column Types, then look at the "On Leave" column.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I may need to use this option if I can't get the javascript option to work.